# Apache Tomcat installed and running, but localhost:8080 presents blank page in browser

Tags: tomcat

I am using Fedora 16, and I have installed Apache Tomcat, using the `tomcat6` package.

In the terminal I have started Tomcat:

```
[rajani@localhost ~]$ sudo service tomcat6 start
[sudo] password for rajani: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  start tomcat6.service
[rajani@localhost ~]$
```

But if I browse to `http://localhost:8080` it simply shows a blank page.
Please give me solution.

Comment: Do you have any content in ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps, or is that folder empty?

Comment: No any such folders in tomcat,first of all the home page of apache tomcat is not opening.it is blank.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem under Fedora 16; the Tomcat 7 packages installed correctly, but I couldn't see anything at [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080/). I googled around and found that I need to install some additional packages in order for the default webapps to work. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
# sudo yum install tomcat-admin-webapps.noarch tomcat-docs-webapp.noarch tomcat-javadoc.noarch tomcat-systemv.noarch tomcat-webapps.noarch
```

Comment: With Tomcat 6: `sudo yum install tomcat6-webapps tomcat6-docs-webapp tomcat6-admin-webapps`, see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/107400/tomcat-manager-application-and-http-404-error

Comment: i ran tomcat server through eclipse which is on windows machine. I can see my war is extracted in webapps folder also. but empty page is displaying

Comment: Same issue on CentOS 7. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no content in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps, then yes you will see a blank empty page.

Have you installed the tomcat6-webapps rpm? This provides the ROOT and examples web applications for tomcat:

http://pkgs.org/fedora-centos-rhel-opensuse-mandriva/jpackage-5.0-updates-i386/tomcat6-webapps-6.0.35-1.jpp5.noarch.rpm.html

Comment: after installation of yum install tomcat6-webapps if i open tomcat manager it is showing some error page,please give me a solution.

Comment: 403 Access Denied

You are not authorized to view this page.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't configured a user in the conf/tomcat-users.xml file? Follow these instructions : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access, and be sure to restart tomcat after you make the changes

Answer (score 1):

I think you deleted under webapps folder files like root folder etc download or again install some other place copy paste in wep app folder it will work

the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.html
```

where `$CATALINA_HOME` is the root of the Tomcat installation directory. If you're seeing this page, and you don't think you should be, then you're either a user who has arrived at new installation of Tomcat, or you're an administrator who hasn't got his/her setup quite right. Providing the latter is the case, please refer to the Tomcat Documentation for more detailed setup and administration information than is found in the INSTALL file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and Tomcat7. In my case, the /etc/tomcat7/context.xml had two  entries. removing one of them solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly a blank page, but it was an error page:

[image]

I was just missing the path to my page.

I went to "localhost:8080/api/greetings" but I forgot that I wrote

```
server.contextPath=/myapp
```

in my application.properties file(which is located in src/main/resources).

So, the correct path was "localhost:8080/myap/api/greetings".
That was my mistake. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that  ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/ROOT directory is available. ROOT/index.html is the default file that gets loaded when you try to access http://localhost:8080

Comment: There is no such a thing as TOMCAT_HOME. CATALINA_HOME is the environment variable that tomcat looks for.