# Tomcat server is getting started but displaying only blank page when I open it

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am not using any IDE with servlets.
Tomcat server is getting started but when I open it, it only displays a blank page and nothing else.

Comment: have you checked your logs ? Have you checked the tomcat manager to see whether the application was deployed ? did you check your console ?

Comment: What URL are you trying to use for access?

Comment: Maybe can you show us the application code. the jsp something like this so we can look for the problem

Comment: I am not able to open the server home page with the url(localhost:8080)

Comment: We need more details to help you. If your browser doesn't give you a 404 but a blank page it means that Tomcat is ok, it is running but the page page is blank. It may come from your code

Comment: I am not trying to open any deployed application, I am just trying to open the tomcat homepage, using the url I mentioned in above comment.
You got my problem that tomcat is fine, but the blank page is being displayed

Comment: What is you environement? OS, Tomcat version, and how did you install it?

Comment: I am working on windows 7 operating system and my tomcat version is v8.0.15.To install tomcat I downloaded zip file and then I extracted it.

Comment: Confirm that you have something in this directory :  ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/ROOT

Try to access http://localhost:8080/index.jsp

Comment: Yes I do have something in this directory(index.jsp,/WEB-INF,.)

Comment: Do you have something in ${TOMCAT_HOME}/logs/ . Do you have any error for today?

Comment: yes I have various log files and text files in the directory you mentioned

Comment: lets continue this on chat

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Check if you have any error in your logs. Check the content of the blank page. If there is any code then it is probably coming from a bug in the building process of your jsp. If you have any error try to solve it

Comment: Thanks buddy RPresle it is done.

Comment: Tried to sum up our exchange. Feel free to comment the answer to complete it and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several check have to be done:

- ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/ROOT is not empty
- ${TOMCAT_HOME}/logs/ must be checked. If any error is present, it has to be corrected.
- Check the content of the blank page. If there is any code then it is probably coming from a bug in the building process of your jsp.

If the error is on Linux please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189817/apache-tomcat-installed-and-running-but-localhost8080-presents-blank-page-in-b).

Comment: If in IntelliJ, check the tab "Tomcat Localhost log".